# Fragment preparing its view before being shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments (let's call them A and B) inside a fragment activity. Fragment A is simply a placeholder -- an animation of "loading", and works fine. Fragment B draws a chart based off some parsing from websites. That said, it contains a broadcast receiver that handles callbacks from the parsing/loading services. Now the reason I have fragment A is to hide how the bars are being drawn -- one at a time, as they arrive, from inside the broadcast receiver's `onReceive()` method (looks not very pleasant). I launch the parsing/data loading services from inside fragment B's `onCreate()` method. Still, even if fragment B is shown after 5 seconds' delay after fragment A, the bar-chart is still under construction. What I want to accomplish is that whatver fragment B has got to show must be camera-ready when I call the `replace()` method to replace fragment A with fragment B.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, you're showing A and then replacing it with B after 5 seconds. What this means is that B will be created after 5 seconds delay, and the service will only be started at that moment.

What you probably want is: show fragment B, then use `add()` to add fragment A on top of it. Then after a delay, or upon the arrival of the final broadcast (IDK what is feasible), you remove the fragment A, which will reveal your fragment B.

Having said this, strictly speaking, Android will not guarantee your fragment B to always exist underneath the A. It'll probably never happen, but Android reserves the right to destroy it and re-create after A is gone. If you wanted to be thorough and avoid this, I'd look into caching of intermediate responses in the service and only emitting the broadcast when all data is available for the fragment to build the chart.